# Rock Paper Scissors. Java. Methods

Tags: java, methods

I'm assuming this is a logical error.  I can't get the results to add up and I can't get the right results. Every time I enter either rock, paper, scissors, it then decides from there if I've won, lost, or tied.  What is wrong with my code?

```
public class RockPaperScissors {

        public static void displayGreeting()
        {
            String intro = "This program is a game.  A game of Rock, Paper, Scissors\n"+
                           "It is you against the computer.  Rock beats scissors, Paper\n"+
                           " beats rock, and scissors beats paper.  Good luck and may the\n"+
                           "odds be ever in your favor.";
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, intro, "Rock Paper Scissors",1);
        }

        public static String generateComputersChoice()
        {
            Random randomGenrator = new Random();
            int randomNumber = randomGenrator.nextInt(3);

            String weapon = "nothing";
            switch(randomNumber){
            case 0: weapon = "rock";
                break;
            case 1: weapon = "paper";
                break;
            case 2: weapon = "scissors";
                break;
            }
            return weapon;
            }

        public static String enterPlayersChoice(){

            String prompt = "You have a choice of picking rock, paper, or scissors.\n"+
                            "Choose wisely.";

            String input = "";

            input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,prompt,"Choose your weapon",1);
            String inputLower = input.toLowerCase();
            return inputLower;

        }

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            displayGreeting();
          // generateComputersChoice();
           //enterPlayersChoice();
           // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,generateComputersChoice()+ enterPlayersChoice(5));

            String player = enterPlayersChoice();
            String comp = generateComputersChoice();

            int ties = 0;
            int playerWins = 0;
            int compWins = 0;

            for(int i = 0; i < 3; i ++){



                //enterPlayersChoice(); //method

                //generateComputersChoice();  //method
                //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,generateComputersChoice()+ enterPlayersChoice(1));

                //System.out.println(player+ " " + comp);
                //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,player+ " " +comp);

                if(player.equals(comp)){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "It's a tie!");
                    ties ++;

                }
                else if(player.equals("rock")){
                    if(comp.equals("scissors")){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You win!");
                        playerWins ++;

                    }
                }else if(comp.equals("rock")){
                    if(player.equals("scissors")){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You lose!");
                        compWins ++;

                    }
                }else if(player.equals("scissors")){
                    if(comp.equals("paper")){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You win!");
                        playerWins ++;

                    }
                }else if(comp.equals("scissors")){
                    if(player.equals("paper")){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You lose");
                        compWins ++;

                    }
                }else if(player.equals("paper")){
                    if(comp.equals("rock")){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You Win!");
                        playerWins ++;
                    }
                }else if(comp.equals("paper")){
                    if(player.equals("rock")){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You lose!");
                        compWins ++;
                    }
                }else{
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid user input");
                    i--;
                }


            }
          //Results
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Here are the results\n\n"+
                                               "\nTies: " +ties+
                                               "\nComputer Wins: " +compWins+
                                               "\nPlayer Wins: " + playerWins+
                                               "\n\n Program Terminating", "Results",1);


      }

     }
```

Comment: What results are you getting when you run it?

Comment: I input either rock paper or scissors.  Then it decides whether I've won, tied or lost but it won't "reiterate" after that. After that it just says i've either won, lost, or tied 3 times in a row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Then it decides whether I've won, tied or lost but it won't
>   "reiterate" after that. After that it just says i've either won, lost,
>   or tied 3 times in a row

What you're actually doing is asking the input one time and then run the loop, so obviously you'll get the same result 3 times.

You need to ask at **each** iteration the user input :

```
        String player;
        String comp;

        int ties = 0;
        int playerWins = 0;
        int compWins = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i ++){
            player = enterPlayersChoice();
            comp = generateComputersChoice();
            /**/
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you must get the player's choice and the computer's choice each loop.  Move

```
String player = enterPlayersChoice();
String comp = generateComputersChoice();
```

inside the `for` loop at the start.

Also, if you say

```
else if(player.equals("rock")){
   if(comp.equals("scissors")){
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You win!");
        playerWins ++;
}
```

Then the `else if` block will match when the player chooses "rock" regardless of the computer's choice.  Then, if the computer doesn't choose "scissors", nothing will happen.

You need *both* conditions to match for this scenario to execute, else the first condition will match but the second might not, and nothing will happen.  Try

```
else if (player.equals("rock") && comp.equals("scissors")){
```

and likewise for the other conditions.

Comment: @Downvoter Please explain what is wrong or what can be improved.

Answer (score 0):

you have regenerate the the user and computer's choices each time through the loop.
move

```
String player = enterPlayersChoice();
String comp = generateComputersChoice();
```

into the loop else it will be the same all 3 times